# Appending to text in Microsoft Word using Wildcards and find & replace

Tags: ms-word

right now I have a list of 5000 terms in MS Word.

I would like to simply like to place a "--" before and after every number. I would also like to place an -- at the end of the translated english sentence.

The text currently looks like:

> 1 le --  the; him, her, it, them -- vive la politique, vive l'amour -- long live politics, long live love
>
> 2 de-- of, from, some, any -- il ne rêve que d'argent et de plaisirs -- he only dreams of money and pleasure
>
> 3 un -- a, an, one -- je me suis cassé un ongle -- I broke one of my fingernails
>
> 4 à -- to, at, in -- ils restent à l'école le plus longtemps possible -- they remain at school as long as possible

Therefore the corrected text would look like:

> -- 1 -- le --  the; him, her, it, them -- vive la politique, vive l'amour -- long live politics, long live love --
>
> -- 2 -- de-- of, from, some, any -- il ne rêve que d'argent et de plaisirs -- he only dreams of money and pleasure --
>
> -- 3 -- un -- a, an, one -- je me suis cassé un ongle -- I broke one of my fingernails --
>
> -- 4 -- à -- to, at, in -- ils restent à l'école le plus longtemps possible -- they remain at school as long as possible --

I'm familiar with MSOffice's Help regarding the [Use of wildcard characters to find or replace text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-wildcard-characters-to-find-or-replace-text-610E37DC-BB2F-4A8B-8FA5-AA991160EAFB) I just haven't been able to figure out the appropriate strings.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include what you have tried from next time.

Find what: `([0-9]{1,4})[ ]`

Replace with: `--\1--`

additional [ ] is just to denote space. you can simply put space.

Tested in windos 7 pro. 64 bit, office 2010 32 bit.

Depending on your environment, list separator may change. for me its comma like `{1,4}`. For some environments it is semicolon like this. `{1;4}`.

To make it more specific you can also include regex like this. `([0-9]{1,4})[ ]([àldua])` and replace it with `--\1-- \2`

Comment: Thank you, I'll absolutely include my word next time!